# leafleft/mapbox markers stack on top of each other

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

This is how I create map and add markers to it:

```
var map,
    cinemaLayer;

map = L.mapbox.map('map-player', 'XXX', {
    zoom: 10,
    minZoom: 10,
    maxZoom: 14,
});

cinemaLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer();

marker = {
    lat: 48.8656,
    long: 2.3246,
    layer: {}
};

marker.layer = L.marker(L.latLng(marker.lat, marker.long), {
    icon: L.divIcon({
        className: 'marker-cinema-location',
        iconSize: [40, 65]
    })
});

marker.layer.addTo(cinemaLayer);
```

When you zoom out, the markers appear to be on top of each other:

[image]

I am guessing this is some sort of marker spreading option. How to disable it?

Comment: `className: 'marker-cinema-location'` - It could be your CSS paddings or margins, I have seen those add up when configured wrong (although with another Leaflet plugin). It does not spread markers by default.

Comment: You are right. It was. That or whatever else related to using `L.divIcon`. I have switched to the default icon and it works fine. Thanks, I will investigate it further. Add this as an answer, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaflet does not spread markers by default.

You are using a custom CSS class for your markers. Check your CSS paddings, margins and borders. They sometimes add up.